# connecting to smarter stats through cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to get connected to smarter stats website by by passing the login window and load the statistics in a fancybox page

so far this is my code: but that does not seems to be working

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/" resolveurl="true" redirect="true">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="ctl00$MPH$txtUserName" value="test.ca">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="ctl00$MPH$txtPassword" value="mypwd!">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="ctl00$MPH$txtSiteId" value="12343">
</cfhttp>
<cfif cfhttp.statuscode EQ '200 OK'>
    <cfhttp result="results" url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/default.aspx"/>
    <cfoutput>
        #results.filecontent#
</cfoutput>     
</cfif>
```

problem is every time i load the page

http://domain.in/index.cfm 
it comes back to 
http://domain.in/stats/Login.aspx

I am using hostek website's stats provide for a domain

Comment: Using password protected sites with cfhttp can be a pain because you'll have to figure out what cookies are used to associate the connection with a security login.  Then you'll need to pass those cookies with all the cfhttp calls that you make after that.

Comment: SmarterStats does have a web service interface that might work better than cfhttp.  http://stats.smartertools.com/services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is behaving this way is because the initial URL you have in your `cfhttp` tag is returning an HTTP 302 redirect.  Then because you have the `redirect` attribute of the `cfhttp` tag set to `true` it is actually performing the redirect. Look at the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) for that attribute:

> **redirect** - If the response header includes a Location field AND ColdFusion receives a 300-series (redirection) status code, specifies whether to redirect execution to the URL specified in the field:
>
> - yes: redirects execution to the specified page.
> - no: stops execution and returns the response information in the cfhttp variable, or throws an error if the throwOnError attribute is True.
>     The cfhttp.responseHeader.Location variable contains the redirection path. ColdFusion follows a maximum of four redirects on a request. If there are more, ColdFusion functions as if redirect = "no".
>     **Note:** The cflocation tag generates an HTTP 302 response with the url attribute as the Location header value.

So instead of using that initial URL for your `cfhttp` request, try using the URL it is redirecting to. And set the `redirect` attribute to `false`. But be aware that having that attribute set to false the tag will throw an error if it gets a redirect status code so you will need to handle that.

Example:

```
<cfhttp method="post" 
        url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/Login.aspx" 
        resolveurl="true" 
        redirect="false">
```

Comment: i will try that today and see what i get, keep you posted here

Comment: Hi @miguel : I tried your code and got this now, it says object moved and show 302 found in response header http://prntscr.com/evbwad

Comment: Did you change the URL as well as the `redirect` attribute?  You should be requesting from `https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/Login.aspx` which is where the 302 Found is telling you to go. Notice it is `Login.aspx` not `default.aspx`.

Comment: i did not changed anything, i just pasted what i m sending in my request, this is whai m passing `<cfhttp method="post" url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/" resolveurl="true" redirect="false">`

Comment: i changed the url as you specified and go to this address and check http://gr-group.in/stats/index.cfm

Comment: Ok so looks like you are getting passed the issue you asked about in this question. Accept this answer if it helped you and ask a new question (if you have one).

Comment: Can i ask a related question, because now i get to need to get pass the authentication of this page and it seems to doing with javascript

Comment: Sure but please ask it as a new question. Otherwise this question/answer will become irrelevant. You can always refer back to this question if you think it is needed.